# How to pass state from hook to display in App hook in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management, react-state

How do I send the state(data) of `info` to the App hook, so that I can display the properties in divs? `setInfo(info)` stores the data I want to display on the Map hook and I can see all the properties when I `console.log(info)` in `_onClick`. I am stuck on how to use and show it in App. Thanks for the help.

**App**

```
const App = () => {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="inner-left map-container">
        <Map />
      </div>
      <div className="inner-right info-container">
        <Nav />
        <Search />
        <div id="info_side">
          {info} // throws an error undefined
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Map**

```
const Map = () => {
    ...
    const [info, setInfo] = useState(null)

    ...

    const _onClick = event => {
        const { features } = event;
        const info = features && features.find(f => f.layer.id === 'icon');
        setInfo(info); // This is what I would like to use in App
    }

    return (
        <ReactMapGL
            {...viewport}
            onViewportChange={_updateViewport}
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            mapStyle={mapStyle}
            mapboxApiAccessToken={TOKEN}
            onHover={_onHover}
            onClick={_onClick}>

            <Source id="my-data" type="geojson" data={geojson}>
                <Layer {...icon} />
            </Source>

            <div style={navStyle}>
                <NavigationControl onViewportChange={_updateViewport} />
                ...
            </div>
        </ReactMapGL>
    );
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: This `const Map` is a bad name. It might conflict with ES6's Map.

Comment: To answer your query, you can use callbacks to share data between components or use a state-management-system like Flux, Redux to store global state

Comment: how do I do this with a callback? I would like to steer clear of Redux at the moment if possible (thank you for the suggestion on const Map, I agree I will update that)

Comment: It's a long uphill battle but I'll save you some time, in react data generally flows in one direction, from parent to child component, in the form of props. You can pass a callback function prop to a child to call (on mounting for example) to "pass data" back to the parent to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a callback prop to the child.

**App**

```
const App = () => {

  const [info, setInfo] = useState(); // local info state

  const displayInfo = () => {
    // this is where I would hope to return the <div>'s with data such as <div>info.Company</div>
    // access current copy of info
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="inner-left map-container">
        <Map onInfoChange={setInfo} /> // pass info state setter to child
      </div>
      <div className="inner-right info-container">
        <Nav />
        <Search />
        <div id="info_side">
          {displayInfo}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Map**

```
const Map = ({
  onInfoChange, // passed callback prop
}) => {
    ...
    const [info, setInfo] = useState(null)

    // use an effect hook to call callback whenever info updates
    useEffect(() => {
      onInfoChange(info); // pass info back to parent
    }, [info]);

    const _onClick = event => {
        const { features } = event;
        const info = features && features.find(f => f.layer.id === 'icon');
        setInfo(info); // This is what I would like to use in App
    }

    return (
        <ReactMapGL
            {...viewport}
            onViewportChange={_updateViewport}
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            mapStyle={mapStyle}
            mapboxApiAccessToken={TOKEN}
            onHover={_onHover}
            onClick={_onClick}>

            <Source id="my-data" type="geojson" data={geojson}>
                <Layer {...icon} />
            </Source>

            <div style={navStyle}>
                <NavigationControl onViewportChange={_updateViewport} />
                ...
            </div>
        </ReactMapGL>
    );
}

export default Map;
```

At this point I should point out that you now have duplicate state stored in two components so it's a great idea to hoist the info state and logic to the closest common ancestor (App) and simply pass the info as a prop to the component that needs it (Map). **Single source of truth principle**. Or as other have pointed out, switch to a global state management system, like redux, or roll your own using React Context (i.e. what react-redux is using under the hood).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation Drew, it was very helpful. When on App, how do I display {info}? It console.logs correctly when I click on the <Map/>, however if I do return ( <div>{info.properties}</div> ) on App it throws the error undefined on the initial load.

Comment: `const [info, setInfo] = useState(); // local info state` could be passed some initial state so it is defined on the initial render. `const [info, setInfo] = useState({ properties: '' }); // local info state` would the trick for the specific error you mention.

Answer (score 0):

If several components share state, the state should be managed by the first common ancestor and passed down via properties. In your case, App should manage the state and pass what you need to Map as props.
But how do we update the parent state based on a child event? Create the event handler on the parent and pass it to the child component as a callback function via props.

For example, on your app create the callback function function:

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState({});

const handleEvent = event => {
        // Do whatever you need here
        setInfo(info); 
    }
```

Pass info (the state) and the callback function to the child via props:

```
<Map info={info} clicked={handleEvent}/> //Do not use handleEvent(), otherwise it will call the function immediately
```

On Map, use the props and set clicked as event listener:

```
const Map = ({info, clicked}) => { // destructuring pros.info and props.clicked

  <ReactMapGL
            {...viewport}
            onViewportChange={_updateViewport}
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            mapStyle={mapStyle}
            mapboxApiAccessToken={TOKEN}
            onHover={_onHover}
            onClick={clicked}>
```

See more info here 
https://towardsdatascience.com/passing-data-between-react-components-parent-children-siblings-a64f89e24ecf